# UCB1 for Multi Armed Bandit is stochastic or deterministic?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit

I would like to know if UCB1 for multi armed bandit problems is deterministic or stochastic.

I understand that the arm chosen depends on the expected reward and the "width" of the upper bound, which depends on the number of times I have pulled that arm. So my guess is it's deterministic, but I'm not sure.
Also I am supposing my MAB is not dealing with adversarial rewards - is this the key to say it's deterministic?

- edit - I have since found that it should be stochastic, as opposed adversarial. How can I understand this though? Does this mean than adversarial is deterministic? I wouldn't have said so, the only difference is who/what is giving me my rewards, but I have the same knowledge in the two cases, I guess? Could you help clarify?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, Claire, and welcome to the site!  For people who aren't up on their multi-armed bandit technology, it would help if you wrote out the acronyms the first time you used them, although I'm pretty sure that MAB is "Multi-Armed Bandit".

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you are right, will correct right now! 
Could you help me with my question? I have since found that it should be stochastic, as opposed adversarial. How can I understand this though? Does this mean than adversarial is deterministic? I wouldn't have said so, the only difference is who/what is giving me my rewards, but I have the same knowledge in the two cases, I guess?
Could you helo clarify? Thanks! (imma add this to the OP as well)

Answer (score 3):

UCB1 is a deterministic algorithm, as at each decision-making point (play of the bandit) it selects the best alternative by a deterministic rule:

$$ \text{action} = \arg \min_j \bar{x}_j + \sqrt{2\log(t)/n_j}$$

where $t$ is the iteration count, $n_j$ is the number of times we've already chosen action $j$, and $\bar{x}_j$ is the average reward we've seen from choosing action $j$.  There is no randomness in the selection of $\text{action}$ given our state of knowledge $(t, n_j, \bar{x}_j)$ at each decision point, hence the designation of "deterministic".

The rewards are random, but that does not make the algorithm itself a stochastic algorithm, although the sample path of actions chosen is random because the results of the bandit play are random.

Adversarial or non-adversarial has nothing to do with it.  Decision-making algorithms in adversarial games can be either deterministic or stochastic.

Comment: What you said makes complete sense to me. 
Here's what I found: The one thing we need to have a full definition of the problem is the
characterization of the reward: Deterministic (trivial), Stochastic, Adversary. R is an set of unknown distributions.
From then on there are 2 main chapters, stochastic MAB and Adversarial MAB.
What the slides are saying are not in opposition to what you said right? The slides referring to the rewards, while the question Is UCB1 a deterministic or a stochastic algorithm? refers to how I choose which arm to pull. THANK YOU!
PS Shouldn't it be 2log(t)/n_j?

Comment: @Claire A small addition: typically, ties are broken randomly (if the UCB1 equation gives the same score to multiple different arms). At least, in good implementations of the algorithm that's done. That could technically be viewed as making the algorithm nondeterministic... but obviously that's just a technicality, and only applies to rare cases

Comment: You're right about $n_i$, @Claire, I'll fix that.

Comment: I also hope I'm right about the rest ;) Thank you so much for this discussion, really helped!

Comment: Yes, you are right, the deterministic vs. stochastic part refers to how you choose which arm to pull, not to how the rewards are generated.